# How to use extended SLF4J with Logback

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

We have extended SLF4J's `Logger` API and created `AppLogger` interface. We have to do this for certain need which I cannot disclose here. Now, we want to use this extended logger with **LogBack** framework. I am not able to find any mechanism how to make it work. Direct usage is throwing `ClassCastException` (this is obvious because it is expecting a class with name `Logger` and getting `AppLogger`).

I am able to make this extended interface work with `Log4J 1.x` and `Log4J 2.x` by writing a bridge implementation and providing custom `StaticBinder` classes. For LogBack, this bridge class (`StaticBinder`) is part of `logback-classic` JAR file, so I am not sure how to write my own binder and bridge LogBack.

The `AppLogger` interface looks like:

```
public interface AppLogger extends org.slf4j.Logger {
    public void myOwnMethod(String message, Object... args);
}
```

Appreciate if anyone provide any idea.

Comment: @Raedwald, I have edited my question to add the extended interface. I have to add few more application specific logging methods. I also understand your point of extending LogBack. I know I have to provide an implementation equivalent of `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` which would extend my `AppLogger`, but in that case, I have to provide code for all the classes present in `logback-classic` JAR. I am not able to think of any other idea. Kindly suggest if you have a different thought.

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine why you might need to extend the core Logger interface to do something that couldn't be done via Markers or MDC or some other of the built-in mechanisms. You're probably better off not adapting the Logger interface but just providing your own method that all your classes static import.

Answer (score 3):

Up to version 1.7.15 SLF4J binding mechanism used to be very very very simple. After version 1.7.15, with the introduction of event replay the mechanism got a little more complicated but the core binding idea remains simple. Moreover, for those who can't be bothered, any support for event replay can be safely omitted.

For examples of slf4j bindings, see code in slf4j-nop or slf4j-simple modules.

However, from what I gather, you wish use an extended Logger API in which case you should look into `LoggerWrapper`, `XLogger` and `XLoggerFactory` classes in the slf4j-ext module. You should be able to easily emulate the same procedure for your `AppLogger` interface.